# How do I make Visual Studio 2015 always open files in the main window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, I have my find window in it's own window on my second monitor. When I double click on a file, I want it to open on my main monitor in the main window in a tab next to the rest of my code, but instead it opens in a tab next to the find results.

Anybody know how to change this behaviour?

Comment: where is you find window? I mean is it in side main visual studio window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undock "Find Window" from Visual Studio Window, and move it to second monitor.

Solution explorer always opens new file docked in side main window.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I could undock all the tabs from the second window and then it would behave more like earlier versions of VS. Txx.